# O365 Sharepoint subsite vs O365 Group

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, team-sites, office-365-groups

Does anyone know the major differences between creating an Office 365 group (which comes with a Sharepoint team site) and just creating a team subsite in an existing Sharepoint site collection?

My company recently switched away from using Sharepoint 2016 and instead got Office 365, which comes with Sharepoint online (I think it's Sharepoint online). The default action when you create a new subsite in the Sharepoint app is not to create a subsite under the main site collection, but instead to create an Office 365 group with it's own team site and shared calendar and OneNote and OneDrive and email distro group, all of which show up in the relevant apps.

My question is this: can I get those same connections by just creating a team site normally? I like the functionality of having connected applications where the connections are present in apps outside of Sharepoint, but it's a pain in the butt to manage permissions and such for each group since the sites do not show up as subsites under the main Sharepoint site.

Does anyone else have experience using Office 365 Sharepoint and Office 365 groups?